# Compilation error using eclipse

Tags: c, compiler-errors

In the following header file i declared some functions:

```
    #ifndef _MY_INT_FUNCTIONS_H_
    #define _MY_INT_FUNCTIONS_H_



    int intFcn (const void *key, size_t table_size);
    void intPrint (const void *key);
    int intCompare (const void *key1, const void *key2);


    #endif // _MY_INT_FUNCTIONS_H_
```

but i get a compilation error saying:

"expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’"

regarding the int intFcn function.

im using eclipse INDIGO version.

help anyone?

Comment: I think you should include stdlib.h

Comment: Another example of the horrific and inappropriate error messages most C compilers issue. Why doesn't the compiler just say "Unrecognized type" instead?

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev : because of the way parsers work. The parser expects something, but sees something else, so it gives an error stating exactly that. Nicer error messages generally mean more complex parsers. Given that C++ parsers are already quite complex (due to the nature of the C++ grammar), that is a difficult task. I agree having nicer error messages would be interesting, but it's hard to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ `size_t` is declared in the `<cstddef>` header in the `std` namespace.

```
#include <cstddef>

int intFcn (const void *key, std::size_t table_size);
```

In C (and in C++ too), it's declared in `<stddef.h>`:

```
#include <stddef.h>

int intFcn (const void *key, size_t table_size);
```

Answer (score 4):

For `size_t`, you need to :

```
#include <stddef.h>   // in C
```

or :

```
#include <cstddef>    // in C++
```